# Error encountered during terminal catkin build ocs2(ubuntu20)

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, ocs

install ocs2
run `catkin build ocs2` in terminal

```
Errors     << ocs2_pinocchio_interface:cmake /home/scott/zf/catkin_ws/logs/ocs2_pinocchio_interface/build.cmake.010.log
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:463 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:643 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (pkg_check_modules)
```

listening to https://blog.csdn.net/tuck_frump/article/details/121545716
i tried installing pinocchio but it didn't work